# How to correctly use CONCAT in query

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

This query works perfectly, if i know all three fields. For example: **Name1 Name2 Name3**, or even first two or last two names.

```
SELECT 
  id, forename, middlename, surname 
FROM peoples 
WHERE 
  forename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR 
  middlename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR 
  surname LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR 
CONCAT(forename, ' ',middlename, ' ',surname) LIKE '%$search_keyword%' ORDER BY forename DESC LIMIT 50";
```

However, it is not working, if i am searching for the same result, but without knowing all names.

For example: **Name1 Name3**, gives me 0 results.

**Example:** if i type **John Lewis**, but the full name for this one is **John Shop Lewis**, it must find this result.

Also, person might not have middlename, so by default it is set to null.

Comment: What should it return ? Could you show us an extract from your DB ? Plus, there's a typo in your `CONCAT`: you wrote `middlenames` instead of `middlename`

Comment: @roberto06 Please check updated question

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER is *fairly* meaningless

Comment: Since there are many permutations of the name, it might be easier to break it up and search each individual part of the name.

Comment: @aynber any suggestions how to do this? I dont think that explode would be the best solution for this one

Comment: Explode would work, and you can use a foreach to build up the query. I'll add it as an answer because it's a bit complicated for a comment.

Comment: @aynber waiting

Comment: could you just change your search inputs to have separate fields for first, middle, and last?

Comment: The correct way is 'not at all'. To a rough approximation, there is no query for which CONCAT or GROUP_CONCAT need form any part  of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `OR CONCAT(forename, ' ',surname) LIKE '%search_keyword%'` ?

(That is, if you absolutely want to do it in SQL and not with PHP's `explode`, as suggested by @aynber in their comments.

```
| id | forename | middlename | surname |
|----+----------+------------+---------|
| 1  | John     | Shop       | Smith   |
| 2  | John     | NULL       | Smith   |
```

The following query

```
SELECT id, forename, middlename, surname 
FROM peoples
WHERE 
    forename LIKE '%John Smith%'
    OR middlename LIKE '%John Smith%'
    OR surname LIKE '%John Smith%' 
    OR CONCAT(forename, ' ',middlename, ' ',surname) LIKE '%John Smith%'
    OR CONCAT(forename, ' ',surname) LIKE '%John Smith%'
ORDER BY forename LIMIT 50
```

Will return both lines 1 and 2.

Comment: @aynber's solution is the best way to go IMHO.

Comment: This solution was best for my code which is already VERY difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are many permutations of names, it's easier to break it apart and search for each particular section, like this:

```
$names = explode(' ',$search_keyword);
$concat_arr = array();
foreach($names as $name) {
    $concat_arr = "CONCAT(forename, ' ',middlename, ' ',surname) LIKE '%$name%'";
}
$query = "SELECT 
  id, forename, middlename, surname 
FROM peoples 
WHERE ";
$query .= implode(' AND ',$concat_arr);
$query .= " ORDER BY forename DESC LIMIT 50";
```

Comment: Thanks, your code also worked, but me and my colleague think, that answer from @roberto06 was better for us.